# Re-directing output of C code as input to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, c, windows

I want to compile a C program related to databases in Windows. I have installed MySQL.

**What I actually want to do is re-direct the output of my  C code as an input command for my database.**

I have done this thing in Ubuntu having followed the below given link:

- [Connecting to MySQL through C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896963/connecting-to-mysql-through-c)

P.S. Does it require for me to compile the code in Command Prompt (because that's how I access the MySQL server).

How do I do it?

Comment: The referenced question shows how to write a program that connects direct to MySQL using its native C API.  That's one (quite good) way to do it.  You could use an ODBC driver instead if you preferred.  The main alternative is probably to have your C program generate the SQL statements and then pipe the output of that program to the `mysql` command-line interpreter.  This is simpler in some respects, but handling errors is much harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - you can compile the code anyhow.

If you want to redirect output, it's easiest to make the program a console application (which can be compiled from the IDE or from the command line).

Then you pipe the output of the program to the mysql command line client.

```
yourprogram | mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name
```